# How to hide logs in log.html from public

Tags: html, .htaccess, security, web

So I saw this code for making logs in a chatbox but

Whenever I typed www.example.com/log.html

It displays all the logs in the chatbox in public.

Is there a way to keep it hidden from public?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .htaccess will help you to moderate control over what others can access.

Comment: Oh.. Thank you so much. It solved my problem... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a .htaccess file in the folder containing the log file. In your case, it seems to be the Web root directory.

```
<Files log.html>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```